# Django - Pre-populating a ModelForm with parameters passed in url

Tags: django, modelform

I am trying to pre-populate a ModelForm with data from an url but get the following error message:

```
Reverse for 'create_entry' with arguments '(1, datetime.date(2019, 11, 1))' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['create_entry/<int:habit_id>/(?P<selected_day>\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})/$', 'create_entry/$']
```

Note that `Habit` is a foreign key. If I take out `habit.id` from the url, the error goes away but the form doesn't get pre-populated and the url is not declared properly.

My question is: what do I need to change ? the ModelForm ? The urls ? The view ?

Thank you for your help !

the relevant url (from within the `habitap` namespace):

```
re_path(r'^create_entry/<int:habit_id>/(?P<selected_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', create_entry, name='create_entry')
```

Comment: Can we see your urls and views too? It's likely that's where the issue lies.

Comment: `date.isoformat()` --> `{% url 'habitap:create_entry' habit.id date|date:"c" %}`

Comment: Thank you Bear. I tried but I didn't work. My intuition is that the date is not the problem. I managed to make the link work on a view that didn't require `habit.id`, but did require `date`

Comment: what error do you have after apply the filter?

Comment: `Reverse for 'create_entry' with arguments '(1, '2019-11-01')' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['create_entry/<int:habit_id>/(?P<selected_day>\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})/$', 'create_entry/$']`

Comment: try manually `{% url 'habitap:create_entry' 1 2019-11-01 %}`

Comment: `Could not parse the remainder: '-11-01' from '2019-11-01'`

Comment: try {% url 'habitap:create_entry' 1 '2019-11-01' %} with the date set in single quotes

Comment: it didn't work , but then again hardcoding the url `/create_entry/1/2019-11-12/` doesn't return anything either

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLUTION !

Django doesn't seem to like mixing type of declaration in the url:

I previously had: 
're_path(
        r'^create_entry/<int:habit_id>/(?P<selected_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', create_entry, name='create_entry')'

but it should be:

're_path(
        r'^create_entry/(?P<habit_id>\d+)/(?P<selected_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', create_entry, name='create_entry')'

Thank you all for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the url, which should have been declared using only regex:

```
re_path(r'^create_entry/(?P<habit_id>\d+)/(?P<selected_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', create_entry, name='create_entry')
```